# Show that for all $n$ $\sigma(n) \leq n^{3/2} + n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer, show that 
$$\sigma(n) \leq n^{3/2}+n$$

I'm not sure how to prove this.  I believe i'm suppose to use this result I just proved, $n$ is composite if and only if $\sigma(n) \geq n + \sqrt{n}$ but i'm not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: It seems difficult to use a lower bound for $\sigma(n)$ to prove an upper bound for $\sigma(n)$.

Comment: I guess that is true, they came as a part (a) part (b) question so I assumed (b) used part (a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the ratio $g(n) = \sigma(n)/n^{3/2}$ is a multiplicative function of $n$, and you should be able to check that the only prime power $p^k$ for which $g(p^k) > 1$ is $p^k=2^1$, and then further check that the only integer $n$ for which $g(n) > 1$ is $n=2$. That is more than enough to establish the desired inequality.